# Additional Pay order button on the WooCommerce order pay page

Tags: php, wordpress, button, woocommerce, submit

On the **WooCommerce payment** page, the order registration button is located at the bottom of the page, and by clicking on it, you will be connected to the payment portal.

Now I want to put another button like that in the middle of the page so that the customer does not have to go to the bottom of the page to go to the payment portal.

There is such a code in the `*form-pay.php*` file for the order button on the **WooCommerce payment** page:

```
<?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_pay_order_button_html', '<button type="submit" class="button alt' . esc_attr( wc_wp_theme_get_element_class_name( 'button' ) ? ' ' . wc_wp_theme_get_element_class_name( 'button' ) : '' ) . '" id="place_order" value="' . esc_attr( $order_button_text ) . '" data-value="' . esc_attr( $order_button_text ) . '">' . esc_html( $order_button_text ) . '</button>' ); // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine ?>
```

But by copying and pasting this code in the middle of the page, I get an error.

**In summary:**

Repeat the order registration button in the  **`form-checkout.php`** file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue using your code is that  `$order_button_text` variable is not defined...

Here below I have made a shortcode function with the correct button code for Order pay page *(for checkout page see the addition below)*:

```php
add_shortcode( 'pay_order_button', 'pay_order_button_shortcode' );
function pay_order_button_shortcode() {
    $order_button_text = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_pay_order_button_text', __( 'Pay for order', 'woocommerce' ) );
    return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_pay_order_button_html', 
        '<button type="submit" class="button alt' . 
        esc_attr( wc_wp_theme_get_element_class_name( 'button' ) ? ' ' . 
        wc_wp_theme_get_element_class_name( 'button' ) : '' ) . 
        '" id="place_order" value="' . esc_attr( $order_button_text ) . 
        '" data-value="' . esc_attr( $order_button_text ) . '">' . 
        esc_html( $order_button_text ) . '</button>' );
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> Note: this should be used inside the main `<form>`

**Usage:**

You can use it as a normal shortcode `[pay_order_button]`.

You can use it in any PHP code:

```
echo do_shortcode("[pay_order_button]");
```

---

Addition 1 : For **checkout page** button:

If you want to add a secondary "Place Order" button on checkout page, you will use the following shortcode function:

```php
add_shortcode( 'place_order_button', 'checkout_place_order_button_shortcode' );
function checkout_place_order_button_shortcode() {
    $order_button_text = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_button_text', __( 'Place order', 'woocommerce' ) );
    return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_button_html', 
        '<button type="submit" class="button alt' . 
        esc_attr( wc_wp_theme_get_element_class_name( 'button' ) ? ' ' . 
        wc_wp_theme_get_element_class_name( 'button' ) : '' ) . 
        '" name="woocommerce_checkout_place_order" id="place_order" value="' . 
        esc_attr( $order_button_text ) . '" data-value="' . 
        esc_attr( $order_button_text ) . '">' . 
        esc_html( $order_button_text ) . '</button>' ); // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine
}
```

**Usage:**

You can use it as a normal shortcode `[place_order_button]`.

You can use it in any PHP code:

```
echo do_shortcode("[place_order_button]");
```

You can use it in a hooked function like *(displayed here before order review section)*:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review', 'additional_checkout_order_button' );
function additional_checkout_order_button() {
    echo do_shortcode("[place_order_button]");
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> Note: this should be used inside the main `<form>`

---

Addition 2: An additional Submit button to be used inside or **outside** the main `<form>`, in the Checkout page or the Order Pay page, using a bit of jQuery enqueued code:

```php
add_shortcode( 'submit_button', 'additional_submit_button_shortcode' );
function additional_submit_button_shortcode() {
    if( ! is_checkout() ) return;

    if ( is_wc_endpoint_url('order-pay') ) {
        $order_button_text = esc_html( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_pay_order_button_text', __( 'Pay for order', 'woocommerce' ) ) );
        $form_selector     = 'form#order_review';
    } else {
        $order_button_text = esc_html( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_button_text', __( 'Place order', 'woocommerce' ) ) );
        $form_selector     = 'form.form.checkout';
    }
    // Enqueuing some Javascript
    wc_enqueue_js( "$('body').on( 'click', 'button#submit_order', function(){
         $('$form_selector').submit();
    });");

    return sprintf('<button type="button" class="button alt" id="submit_order">%s</button>', $order_button_text );
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

**Usage:**

You can use it as a normal shortcode `[submit_button]`.

You can use it in any PHP code:

```
echo do_shortcode("[submit_button]");
```

Comment: Hello. I tested your code. In the first code, the behavior of the created button is not the same as the WooCommerce order registration button. But in the second code, in the line where you defined the `$order_button_text`  variable, it gives the following error: Parse error: **syntax error, unexpected token ","**

Comment: I just want to have a button with the behavior of the WooCommerce checkout button. Your first code created the button but didn't react when it was clicked. However, by clicking on the order button on the WooCommerce payment page, the page was refreshed and displayed an error related to the absence of necessary fields. I am looking for something like this.

Comment: I have updated the code, no more error.

Comment: The button was created but it did not react when clicked. But by clicking on the default button on the WooCommerce payment page, it immediately connected me to the payment gateway. I want the generated button to behave exactly like the default WooCommerce button.

Comment: I have tested both codes, and they work, but the button needs to be inside the main form. If not you will need something different with a bit of javascript…

Comment: Meanwhile, I am testing on **localhost**. I copied your code in the `functions.php` file and put the shortcodes you created in different parts of the `form-checkout.php` page, and again the button didn't show any reaction. Is my method wrong? Also, I copied the default button on the **payment page**, and when I clicked on it, it still didn't react.

Comment: Added a 2nd Addition (at the end), with a shortcode function that displays a button  working on checkout and order pages, everywhere, even outside the main `<form>`. This time this should work for you…

Comment: Hello. I have been looking for a solution to this issue since yesterday. I am very sorry for my late reply. When the **shortcode** `<?php echo do_shortcode("[place_order_button]");  ?>` inside the `<form>` tag, it was exactly what I wanted and my previous mistake was that I put the short code outside the `<form>` tag. But I put the new code you wrote both inside and outside the `<form`> tag, and it didn't show any reaction.I **shortcode** `<?php echo do_shortcode("[submit_button]");  ?>` in the **form-checkout.php** file have`s used.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254229/discussion-between-user21540512-and-loictheaztec).

Comment: I asked a new question. Please check if possible: [Fixed the problem of the code creating the order button on the payment page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76551052/fixed-the-problem-of-the-code-creating-the-order-button-on-the-payment-page)